# how can find php code algorithm

Tags: php, algorithm

I have a php site url and it's encode by base64 and I'm decode it now a part of code this is:

```
a:5:{s:4:"date";s:10:"2017-01-26";s:4:"from";s:5:"10003";s:2:"to";s:5:"10006";s:3:"sec";i:1484761070;s:6:"seckey";i:13910;}
```

now I don't know what is this code algorithm I think i's not json. can you help me?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it has just been serialized.

```
$str = 'a:5:{s:4:"date";s:10:"2017-01-26";s:4:"from";s:5:"10003";s:2:"to";s:5:"10006";s:3:"sec";i:1484761070;s:6:"seckey";i:13910;}';
var_dump(unserialize($str));
```

**Output:**

```
array(5) {
  ["date"]=>
  string(10) "2017-01-26"
  ["from"]=>
  string(5) "10003"
  ["to"]=>
  string(5) "10006"
  ["sec"]=>
  int(1484761070)
  ["seckey"]=>
  int(13910)
}
```